# Does post-install script run when a patch version of the package is installed?

Tags: managed-package, postinstall, patch

Recently we've run into a situation where we've provided an installation link for a patch version of the package (e.g. v1.23.4) to a user, and after this user has successfully installed the patch, the processes listed in the post-install script class appeared to not have run, so the user had to do the steps manually.

Does the post-install script run at all when the patch package is installed on an org? If it does, are there any special limitations for the post-install script when installing a patch version of the package?

Edit: Added sample code from the post-install script which doesn't seem to run:

```
global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
    if (context.isUpgrade()) {
        this.removeCacheDocuments();
        // ...
    }
}

private void removeCacheDocuments() {
    List<Folder> folderList = [select id, name from Folder where name = 'Package Assets'];
    if (folderList.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Folder pkgAssetsFolder = folderList[0];
    List<Document> docList = [
        select id from Document
        where folderId = :pkgAssetsFolder.id
            and (
                name = :ConfigurationService.CACHE_DOCUMENT_A_NAME
                or name = :ConfigurationService.CACHE_DOCUMENT_B_NAME
            )
    ];
    if (!docList.isEmpty()) {
        delete docList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if we can see an excerpt of your post install script. It is possible that the way the code is written prevents the run from happening.

Comment: The context.isUpgrade() call seems a bit fishy to me here, maybe it returns false if the only thing to change is the patch version (major and minor version stay the same)? I couldn't find the documentation on InstallContext methods' behaviour...

Comment: not sure but  I think you need to use `isPush()`  for this. :)